# How to select specific field using Groovy Closure

Tags: groovy, closures

Given:

```
class FruitBasket {
    int apples = 0
    int oranges = 0
}
```

I need to pick out apples from each FruitBasket. The work need to be done in processFruit:

```
def processFruit(list, picker) {
    list.each {
        println "processing " + picker(it)
    }
}

def processAll() {
    List fruitList = [
        new FruitBasket("apples": 2, "oranges": 4),
        new FruitBasket("apples": 3, "oranges": 5)
    ]

    processFruit(fruitList, applePicker)
}

def applePicker(FruitBasket f) {
    return f.getApples()    
}
```

but it is complaining @ runtime that

```
No such property: applePicker for class: FooTest
```

possibly a problem with the closures FruitBasket arg...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that code, applePicker is a method, not a closure.

You can either use a method handle to pass the method as a parameter like so:

```
processFruit(fruitList, this.&applePicker)
```

Or change it to an actual closure:

```
def applePicker = { FruitBasket f -> return f.getApples()    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `applePicker` to `processFruit`, but it is a method.  You can only pass closures this way.  Redefine `applePicker` as a closure like so:

```
applePicker = { FruitBasket f ->
    return f.getApples()
}
```

Or convert the method to a closure when `processFruit` is called:

```
processFruit(fruitList, this.&applePicker)
```